# How to reload react-native app when user press on button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

My use case is to reload the app on the onPress on a button Is there a way we can reload a react native app via code?

Comment: would be better if you explain why you need that and what use cases so the community will able to help you better.

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of a package called react-native-restart

yarn add react-native-restart

react-native link react-native-restart

```
import RNRestart from 'react-native-restart';
 
RNRestart.Restart();
```

Comment: i got error -=> TypeError: null is not object (evaluting'reactNativeRestart.default.Restart') –

Answer (score 2):

There is a question for you.
Why do you need this? If you'd like to update some data on your screen, then you don't need that. If you didn't know, you can declare some newState, and when you press to the button, you can change state of newState, so your component will update, with your datas.

```
const [newState, setNewState] = useState<boolean>(false);

const onClick = () => {
  setNewState(!newState);
}

<Button onClick={onClick} />
```

The thing what you trying to do is bad practice. It is better for you, if you won't do this.

Comment: easy. if the app crashes and you catch it with react-error-boundary, and you just restart.

Answer (score 0):

Following this.

**Installation**

```
npm install --save react-native-restart
```

or

```
yarn add react-native-restart
```

Link to Native Platforms

```
react-native link react-native-restart
```

**Usage**

```
import RNRestart from 'react-native-restart';
import { Button } from 'react-native';

const App = () => {

const startReload = ()=> RNRestart.Restart();

return(
  <>
   <Button title="Reload" onPress={startReload}/>
  </>
}
export default App
```

Comment: i got error -=>  TypeError: null is not object (evaluting'reactNativeRestart.default.Restart')